# unable to access localhost outside my computer

Tags: web-services, iis, webmatrix

I have created a proxy using php on webmatrix . On my local machine I am able to access the website using

//localhost:1136/Tools.php?arg1="test"

however when I try giving the actual machine name(with domain ) I get "Bad Request: Invalid Host Name" . This happens even on my local machine . i.e when I replace localhost by the machine name(domain)

What have I tried ?

I have modified the applicationhost.config in the IISExpress by putting an alias for my website

```
<site name="EmptySite2" id="7">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\xom\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite2" />
                </application>
                <application path="/alias">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="ABCD.xxx.xx.com" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1136:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Modify the applicationhost on  C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
•   Locate the site 
•   Replace the localhost in the binding protocol by your machine name

\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite2" />
                
                                                                
                    " />